# Why Flutter GoRouter ignores pageKey

Tags: flutter, url, browser, navigation

Regarding the [documentation](https://gorouter.dev/nested-navigation) if Flutter identifies the same key it will update the url and keep the page (Widget). In the code below pageKey is a static const value set in both Containers. When navigating between those two routes (/home & /home/login) Flutter ignores it's the same widget and recreates it.

```
class ProjectXApp extends StatelessWidget {

  ProjectXApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const pageKey = ValueKey("Home");

  final _router = GoRouter(
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        redirect: (_) => Routes.routeHome,
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/home',
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Container(key: pageKey);
        }
      ),
      GoRoute(
          path: "/home/login",
          builder: (context, state) {
            return Container(key: pageKey);
          }
      )
    ],
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
        routeInformationParser: _router.routeInformationParser,
        routerDelegate: _router.routerDelegate
    );
  }
}
```

Why is it happening? Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Based on the documentation you've provided it seems like you should've used `state.pageKey` instead of your own custom key.

Comment: True. But Flutter recognizes state.pageKey as the same key only for the same route (also dynamic routes) and same container. If you replace the custom key with state.pageKey you get the same result.

Comment: The reason I used my own unique key is that GoRouter creates it using the path. Dynamic routes have placeholder, so within the same dynamic route the key is the same. But in my case /home and /home/login are the same page but not dynamic. By using state.pageKey you don't get the same key.  
Keys output: 
/home - key: [<'/home'>]
/home/login - key: [<'/home/login'>]

Answer (score 0):

You are understanding the documentation correctly.  I ran into this same issue and I found that switching to context.go(...) from context.push(....) gave me the desired result. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).